# Why is music downloaded from Zune Marketplace often corrupted?

Tags: zune, music

I've had this problem on both the HTC7 Mozart and the Nokia Lumia 800 (both on Orange UK) where occassionally music downloaded directly to the phone from the Zune Marketplace (not synced via Zune desktop app) will not playback correctly. Specific parts of songs appear to be corrupt, if I forward by the corrupt part then the remainder of the song will playback correctly.

On the HTC Mozart this would also ocassionally crash the phone (reason I replaced it with the Lumia). Has anyone else had issues like this and are there any known fixes?

Comment: It sounds weird that his happened twice, do you have any environmental impact on the device (temperature, humidity, pressure, ...) that could damage its storage? Do you notice any other corruption outside of the Zune Marketplace? Perhaps DRM is messing up...

Comment: It's happened more than twice, but i've had the same issue across multiple devices. Drm is a possibility, but if I remove the file and sync it from PC it seems to be fine. Storage damage is unlikely as it only happens when music is downloaded directly to the phone instead of via the zune windows application. All the times it has happened I believe the music has been downloaded via 3G/HDSPA, so it could be corruption while downloading, but I'd expect the files to have error correction, checksum etc.

Comment: If it is a slower connection, it might be possible that they use a correction method that is less accurate as to make the overhead smaller. Although I would highly doubt if that is the case. If it only happens over that type of connection, it would make it the most likely to happen...

Comment: Have you tried to contact via twitter WinPhoneSupport? Maybe they can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't had this happen to me but it happened on my wife's phone. From what I understand, she downloaded it over the cellular network, and some packets were lost in transit. Best thing to do is just delete the old version and try again. If it keeps happening over the cell data plan, switch to WiFi and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: +1 been playing around with it and ran a few tests. It just does seem to be tied to using data connection instead of sync/wifi. Seems like an odd bug to have would have expected error correction + checksumming to fix issues like this even over a data plan. Marked as answer to close question.

Answer (score 3):

I have seen this problem happen to some other people, and it looks like the only common thing between all of them is that they were downloading the songs via their 3G connection. Just to make sure there is no data corruption wait until you are connected via WiFi to download them or sync them via Zune.